# Declare a Function `type` with `implicit` parameters

Tags: scala, implicit

Is it somehow possible to declare something like

```
type F = (Int, Boolean)(implicit String) => Unit
```

in Scala?

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment, it was "you can do type f =  (Int, Boolean) => (String) => Unit anyway".

You're right in saying that it doesn't work with implicits, I guess it's because you should not depend on them in your types. A function that takes an Int and a Boolean is a function that takes an Int and a Boolean regardless of the implicits in scope.

edit: Ok, ven answered below, a method is not a function, and fuctions don't have implicits

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a very important distinction in Scala between "function" and "method":

Functions are values, and can't take arguments by-name, can't be polymorphic, can't be variadic, can't be overloaded, and can't have implicit parameters. While methods can have these, they cannot be passed around as values.

Function types are just traits in the standard library, of the following form:

```
trait FunctionN[T1, ..., TN, R] {
  def apply(x1: T1, ..., xN: TN): R
}
```

Note how the `apply` method in these types does *not* have an implicit parameter list. Therefore, functions won't ever have implicit parameters.

So if you want to pass "functions" that take implicit parameters, you must create your own trait:

```
trait Function2I1[T1, T2, I1, R] {
  def apply(a1: T1, a2: T2)(implicit i1: I1): R
}

type F = Function2I1[Int, Boolean, String, Unit]
```

Now you can create instances of type `F` (albeit not with shiny lambda syntax):

```
val f = new F {
  override def apply(x: Int, y: Boolean)(implicit z: String): Unit = ???
}
implicit val x = "hi"
f(1, true) // implicitly passes x
```

---

If you want curried functions without implicit parameters, just write `(Int, Boolean) => String => Unit`.

If you want to convert a method to a function, use a lambda:

```
class A {
  def f(a: String)(implicit b: String): String = a + b
}
val a = new A
val m = a.f(_) // takes the implicit in this scope
```